# How to write parameter URL in .htacess Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to point this URL in `.htaccess`:

```
http://www.example.com/furniture/chair/foldingchair
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/products.asp?catID=1&SubID=2&SubCatID=3
```

where

- `catID=1` = furniture
- `SubID=2` = chair
- `SubCatID=3` = foldingchair

every parameter have own name like

- `catid=1`  furniture
- `Subid=4`  table
- `subcatId=5` roundtable

but I have few hundreds of URL , so I need a single to that can work for all

```
RewriteRule furniture/chair/foldingchair/?$ products.asp?CatID=1&SubID=2&SubCatID=3
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html)

Comment: ...and `RewriteMap` requires access to the main server config in order to create the rewrite map initially - not something you can do in `.htaccess` only. Do all 3 parameters share the same ID-space (as they appear to in your 2 examples)? Or do you need 3 separate tables?